# Convert a string literal into a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have

```
letters =  ["'FD', 'DD', 'CB', 'AA', 'CB', 'BA', 'BB', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'BA', 'DC', 'CB', 'CC', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'FF'"]
```

and I want to split the first and last " " and create this list

```
letters = ['FD', 'DD', 'CB', 'AA', 'CB', 'BA', 'BB', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'BA', 'DC', 'CB', 'CC', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'FF']
```

Here is my attempt, unfortunately is seems to give me the same list again:

```
a=["'FD', 'DD', 'CB', 'AA', 'CB', 'BA', 'BB', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'BA', 'DC', 'CB', 'CC', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'FF'"]
a="".join(a)
a=a.replace('"'," " )
print a
n=[]
n.append(a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
string = letters[0]
listInDesiredFormat = string.replace('\'', '').split(', ')
```

This takes the string which is the first element of the list, replaces all single quotes and then splits on the comma to obtain a list of strings

Answer (score 3):

First of all, with `letters` you don't have a string, but a list with only one element (which happens to be a string). You can access the string inside with `letters[0]`.

I suggest the use of `ast.literal_eval`, which (basically) is the safe version of `eval`.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> list(literal_eval(letters[0]))
['FD', 'DD', 'CB', 'AA', 'CB', 'BA', 'BB', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'BA', 'DC', 'CB', 'CC', 'FD', 'CC', 'CB', 'FF']
```